# Destructuring assignment in web worker causes an error "_slicedToArray is not defined"

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've try to use simple example in **main js** script and in **web worker** script.

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

And in worker I get an error "*Uncaught ReferenceError: _slicedToArray is not defined*". What could be the reason?

**Update**

Of couse I use webpack/polyfill and final code looks like this:

```
var object1 = {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42
    };

    var _arr = Object.entries(object1);

    for (var _i = 0; _i < _arr.length; _i++) {
      var _arr$_i = _slicedToArray(_arr[_i], 2),
          key = _arr$_i[0],
          value = _arr$_i[1];

      console.log("".concat(key, ": ").concat(value));
    }
```

Comment: please add the code with `_slicedToArray `.

Comment: How are you bundling / shipping the code?

Comment: @ninaScholz probably a polyfill, that doesn't arrive at the webworker.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem and haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: did anyone of you solved it ?